# Failed attempt to verify signature and time stamp

Tags: java, xml-signature, xades4j

I try to verify the signature and the time stamp with this method

```
private static boolean verifyXAdEST(String folder, String file) {
    try {
        FileSystemDirectoryCertStore store = new FileSystemDirectoryCertStore("C:/Certs");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Certs/cert.pfx");
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        ks.load(fis, "SECRET_PASS".toCharArray());                         
        fis.close();            
        CertificateValidationProvider provider = new PKIXCertificateValidationProvider(ks, false, store.getStore());

        XadesVerifier verifier = new XadesVerificationProfile(provider)
                .newVerifier();

        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new File(folder + file));

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        Element sig = (Element)doc.getElementsByTagName("ds:Signature").item(0);

        XAdESVerificationResult result = verifier.verify(
                sig, null, 
                new XadesFormatExtenderProfile().getFormatExtender(),
                XAdESForm.T);


        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

But the method returns Bad XML signature.

Somebody can help me plz!!
Thanks

Comment: Is there any nested exception? Also, I'm not sure why you're using the extender, since the origin signature is already XAdES-T (assuming this is the same as this issue: https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/issues/103)

Comment: For the future visitors the answer is here: https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/issues/103
And the sample code here: https://gist.github.com/JohnnyJosep/29cd545db3d0b7abd23279b56d4db194